# UDP socket programming using python

Tags: python, sockets, udp, distributed-system

I have a pair of code-samples, one for a server and a second for a client.

What I am trying to do is, I want to broadcast the message from a single server to many clients, who listen to that port. So, server sends the message and clients are receiving it and posting it.

First, what I want to know is as follows:

1. How to get the IP-addresses of the multiple client?
2. The pattern I have here is a request-reply, I assume. But is it really replying? I don't think, so all I can see is posting a message and clients may receive it. What pattern does the broadcast message actually follows?

Kindly address my question and hoping for a good understanding response. Thanks

3. Will this code work from different computer as I am using 2 linux VM-s, one for a server and another for a client, I also want to add one more client from my other Linux laptop.
4. My code at server.py stops right after sending a message and does not wait for sending some more message. Why?

## SERVER.PY

```
cs = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)

cs.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

cs.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)

cs.sendto('This is a test', ('<broadcast>', 10000))
```

## CLIENT.PY

```
import select, socket 

port = 10000   

bufferSize = 1024   

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

s.bind(('<broadcast>', port))

s.setblocking(0)

while True:
    result = select.select([s],[],[])
    msg = result[0][0].recv(bufferSize) 
    print msg
```

Comment: Please read the wiki pages, there is no relationship between the code you typed and what you want. If you are going to send data without connecting, you should use a lower-level socket connection. The methods you specify cannot be broadcast!

Comment: So the broadcast message has any pattern?

Comment: Ask this question to  **WIRESHARK**

Comment: ok alright, I understood that the broadcasting means  sending a message or UDP packet to all the receivers and the client has no means of replying to the server. All it does is just receive it.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution i was looking and may be someone might find it useful. But not entirely and few more implementation have to done for more specific needs.

server side:

```
import socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST,1)
s.sendto("this is my message".encode(),('255.255.255.255',10000))
s.close()
```

receiver side:

```
from socket import *
s= socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('', 10000))
m=s.recvfrom(1024)
print(m[0])
```

So the server keeps broadcasting the message and whenever the client goes online and it can recv that default message from the server from the ip - 255x

Answer (score 0):

---

### ZeroMQ would be my choice for doing UDP/multicast

ZeroMQ framework has all the tooling ready and is right-enough for this type of tasks. API documentation has all the details + you may remember my advice on also reading the excellent book "**Code Connected: Volume 1**". Worth time and efforts ( PDF already available ).

Server will **`.bind()`** and clients will **`.connect()`**, using either a **`pgm://`** ( with possible rate-limitation tools ) or an **`epgm://`** transport-class for the actual infrstructure setup and later for any message delivery.

Server-side

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# proper error-state & Event handling is not presented in this mock-up
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
aCtx = zmq.Context()
aPUB = aCtx.Socket( zmq.PUB )
aPUB.bind( "epgm://eth0;239.192.1.1:5556" )
aPUB.setsockopt( zmq.LINGER, 0 )
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# proper error-state & Event handling is not presented in this mock-up
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
while True:
      aPUB.send( binascii.unhexlify( msg + ( "%06X" %id ) ), zmq.NOBLOCK )
      id += 1
      time.sleep( 0.1 )
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# proper error-state & Event handling is not presented in this mock-up
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
aPUB.close()
aCtx.term()
```

Clients will:

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# proper error-state & Event handling is not presented in this mock-up
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
aCtx = zmq.Context()
aSUB = aCtx.Socket( zmq.SUB )
aSUB.connect( "epgm://eth0;239.192.1.1:5556" )
aSUB.setsockopt( zmq.LINGER, 0 )
aSUB.setsockopt( zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "" )
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# proper error-state & Event handling is not presented in this mock-up
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
while True:
      print "INF: Client code in a blocking-wait until any message arrives..."
      print aSUB.recv()
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# proper error-state & Event handling is not presented in this mock-up
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
aSUB.close()
aCtx.term()
```

---

Ad 1 ) the `{ epgm:// | pgm:// }` server-code will not do client-address (re-)discovery
Ad 2 ) No, this is definitely not a `REQ/REP`, but a `PUB/SUB`
Ad 3 ) VM-s inside a seriously designed and configured Hypervisor will work well
Ad 4 ) Original code was not trying to do anything after the first send, thus obvious.

Comment: Hi, In the aSUB.connect() it throws error saying protocol not supported

Comment: Well need to adapt the interface name so that it matches the localhost. Read the API documentation about PGM/EPGM transport-classes and about all options available there for doing this.

Comment: I tried installing zmq from package tar file but still it gives me error in that area.

Comment: Would be great to isolate the root cause. Start with the ZeroMQ python binding version number ( epgm since 2.1.11+ ) and best test the non-python ( best the original C language mock-up, according to the API documentation ).